# Craft 3 Upddate: Plugin Errors

Tags: plugins

I have tried to get a number of plugins from the Plugin Store but each time on install, I get the following errors:

Status: Not Found

Response: {"error":"Template not found: internal_error.html"}

Has anyone seen this as well?

Answer (score 1):

`internal_error.html` isn't a file that is shipped with Craft.

Most likely what is happening is that you're running into some fatal PHP error (like bumping into your php.ini file's `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time` setting) and your host has configured *all* fatal errors (or anything with a 500 Internal Server Error response code) to redirect to their `internal_error.html` template.

Craft doesn't know how to route to that template, so you get the error above.

I'd check Craft's logs at `craft/storage/logs` and/or your web server's error logs for the real underlying error.